# How to add delays in animations in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create a small javascript animation to understand an algorithm better .
The algorithm works on a 2d array like this :-

```
function algorithm(){
    for(var i=0;i<gridSize;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<gridSize;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]=="D"){
                // fill every nearby emty place with 1
            if(i-1>=0 && j-1>=0 && arr[i-1][j-1]=="-"){
                arr[i-1][j-1]=1;
                // change the canvas here.
                    queue.enqueue(new Point(i-1,j-1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and so on .
My function to fill canvas based on array is as :

```
function execute(){
    for(var i=0;i<gridSize;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<gridSize;j++){
            drawRect(i,j);
        }
    }
}
function randomFill(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)
    execute();
    for(var i=0;i<gridSize;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<gridSize;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]=="W")
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            else if(arr[i][j]=="D")
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            else if(arr[i][j] == "-")
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            else
            ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
            ctx.font='30px Calibri';
            ctx.fillText(arr[i][j],i*40 + 40,(j+1)*40 + 40);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I call the randomFill() function to redraw on the canvas after say a 100 ms.
I want to show the change in the array on the canvas but after a little delay , so that people can see.

Comment: Why not just use setTimeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delay an iteration you need to use something else than a for-loop as delaying would involve timers which are asynchronous without exception and can't therefor be used to "sleep" inside a for-loop iteration.

The solution is to break up the for-loops into counters which are incremented every 100ms. It becomes a bit different pattern but enables you to introduce a delay for each "iteration" (or increment).

Here is a basic example setup looping using counters and delays for each iteration - the example is only meant as skeleton which you can use to adopt for your scenario:

```
/* global variables */
var i = 0;                 // outer loop
var j = 0;                 // inner loop

function next() {

    if (j === gridSize) {
        i++;               // increase outer loop counter
        j = 0;             // reset inner loop counter

        if (i === gridSize) {
            /* ...loop has finished, re-initialize etc. here ... */
            return;
        }
    }

    /* ... use i, j here and update canvas - see example link below ... */

    j++;                   // iterate inner counter

    setTimeout(next, 100); // delayed calling of next() again
}
next();                    // start loop
```

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/9E3BW/)**

The next() method simply increased inner loop (`j`) each time it's called. When first criteria is fulfilled (j = gridSize) then `j` is reset and outer loop is increased (`i`).

When also the outer loop meets the criteria (i = gridSize) then the loop is entering an exit point which can be used to re-initialize an array, reset `i` and `j`, restart loop and so on.

`i` and `j` are in the global scope as when you call `setTimeout` the code will be executed with the global window object as scope, so declaring `i` and `j` globally makes them available from inside the function. There are ways around this but I leave this topic out here for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Thank you very much . I applied it and it works . I was looking in the wrong direction . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The new and preferred way of creating animation loops is with `window.requestAnimationFrame`

It's preferred because it coordinates loop execution with the browser refresh rate to produce efficient redraws.  It also suspends the animation loop if the browser switches to a different browser tab (saves battery on mobile devices).

Like setTimeout, requestAnimationFrame (I'll call it RAF for short) is given a callback function to execute.  RAF will execute that callback function in a manor synchronized with the browser and hardware.

Here's what a typical RAF animation loop looks like:

```
function animate(timestamp){

    // execute RAF again to request the next loop
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
```

RAF sends a timestamp to the function it calls (that's the timestamp in animate).  You can use this timestamp to execute your randomFill() after 100ms.

That might look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2afLc/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle="skyblue";
        ctx.strokeStyle="lightgray";
        ctx.lineWidth=4;

        // testing: rotate a rectangle every 100ms        
        var r=0;
        var interval=100;
        $("#interval").text("Call randomFill to rotate every "+interval+"ms");

        // a variable to hold when the animation loop last fired
        var lastTime;

        // start the animation loop
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        function animate(timestamp) {

            // initialize lastTime during the first run of the animate() loop
            if(!lastTime){lastTime=timestamp;}

            // calculate the elapsed time
            var elapsed=timestamp-lastTime;      


            if(elapsed>interval){
                // let randomFill complete before
                // resetting the timer and requesting another loop
                r+=Math.PI/120;
                randomFill(r);
                // reset the timer
                lastTime=performance.now();
            }
            // request another animation loop
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        }        

        function randomFill(r){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(100,100);
            ctx.rotate(r);
            ctx.fillRect(-25,-25,50,50);
            ctx.strokeRect(-25,-25,50,50);
            ctx.restore();
        }

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="interval">Call randomFill</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I use it in such a way that whenever my algorithm loop,it updates the value of ARR element update the canvas using randomFill(); and let it stay it there for 100 ms and not execute the next iteration . How would I do that ???

Comment: Sure, to do that you ask for another loop and reset the `lastTime` variable after you do randomFill.  That way you will get a full 100ms before the timer elapses again.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Oh man , I am a total noob. I still can't get it to function properly . Ok so I copy pasted your code . But nothing happens . I read from many resources from internet , but still I can't get it work . The only thing I want is if you look at my algorithm loop is that whenever I update the value of arr element,I just want to repaint the canvas with randomFill() , but also take a little pause so that the transition could be seen . In short , I just want to slow down every iteration in the loop .

Comment: No problem, I edited my answer with complete code to call randomFill approximately every 100ms.  Note that RAF fires approximately every 60ms (to synchronize with the refresh rate) so that the most efficient elapsed time intervals are multiples of 60ms (so you might use 60*2=120ms instead of 100ms).  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

[**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

```
function randomFill(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)
    execute();
    for(var i=0;i<gridSize;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<gridSize;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]=="W")
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            else if(arr[i][j]=="D")
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            else if(arr[i][j] == "-")
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            else
            ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
            ctx.font='30px Calibri';
            ctx.fillText(arr[i][j],i*40 + 40,(j+1)*40 + 40);
            }
        }
    }
  }, 100); // or however long the delay should be, in ms
}
```

Might also be advisable to make sure you don't overlap timeout requests with clearTimeout, e.g.:

```
  tid && clearTimeout(tid);
  tid = setTimeout(...)
```

Comment: I did try setTimeout as setTimeout(randomFill(),1000); at places where I wanted to update the canvas but it doesn't have any effect . Only the final image in the canvas is shown , not the transitions .

Comment: So close! setTimeout accepts a function. When you call `setTimeout(randomFill(), x)` you are not passing it a function block, you are executing randomFill() and passing the return value to setTimeout(). You want either the way I laid it out in the answer or `setTimeout(randFill, x)` (note: without the parentheses)

Comment: still no clue. So I put setTimeout(function(){randomFill();},1000); wherever I need to update the canvas. But still the canvas waits for 1 sec and shows the final image.